# Asymptotic estimate of weighted sum

Tags: number-theory

I have to find an asymptotic formula for $\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq x} (1+\lambda (n))\left[\frac{x}{n}\right]$.
From an exercise in Apostol,  $$\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq x} \lambda (n)\left[\frac{x}{n}\right] = \sum_{n\leq x}[\sqrt x] = O(x\sqrt x)$$ Also, we know that $$\displaystyle \sum_{n\leq x} \left[\frac{x}{n}\right] = x\log x +(2C - 1)x + O(\sqrt x)$$ Hence, $$\displaystyle\sum_{n\leq x} (1+\lambda (n))\left[\frac{x}{n}\right] = x\log x +(2C - 1)x + O(\sqrt x) + O(x\sqrt x) =  x\log x +(2C - 1)x + O(x\sqrt x)$$ Is this an acceptable estimate?

Comment: no - compare the sizes of the error term and the main term.  (remember, $log x$ is quite small)

Comment: @tomos: Could you please elaborate a bit? I know $log x < x$.

Comment: @User2018 $x\sqrt{x}$ is much larger than $x\log x$ and $(2C-1)x$. The $O(x\sqrt{x})$ will "eat" all the other terms.

Comment: as gary said, it's much larger.  actually it's useful to always have the following in mind: fix $A,C>0$ and $0<B<1$, then $(log x)^A<e^{(log x)^B}<x^C$.  (i hope the middle one is right...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you wrote is correct then
$$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\lambda (n)\!\left[ {\frac{x}{n}} \right]}  = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {[\sqrt x ]}  = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\left( {\sqrt x  + \mathcal{O}(1)} \right)}  = x^{3/2}  + \mathcal{O}(x).
$$
Also,
$$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\left[ {\frac{x}{n}} \right]}  = x\log x + \mathcal{O}(x).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum\limits_{n \le x} {(1 + \lambda (n))\!\left[ {\frac{x}{n}} \right]}  = x^{3/2}  + x\log x + \mathcal{O}(x).
$$